# in Python 3 add dynamically property to class in loop from list or table of key/value pairs

Tags: python

I want to have class containing config pairs key/value. Something like:

```
class Cfg (object):
  def __init__ (self):
    self.f_ = 1  #'f' - first
    self.s_ = 2
    self.t_ = 3
```

Since list of "key/value" pairs could be long I think next would be improvement:

```
class Cfg (object):
  KEY_VALUES = (
    ('f', 1), ('s', 2), ('t', 3)
  )
  def __init__ (self):
    for k, v in Cfg.KEY_VALUES:
      setattr (self, f'{k}_', v)
```

Above works if I access each key as Cfg ().f_ (or Cfg ().s_ and etc)
So, I thought to add "property" for each key as

```
for k, v in Cfg.KEY_VALUES:
  setattr (Cfg, k, property (lambda self: getattr (self, f'{k}_')))
```

And I get unexpected (for myself) result:

```
>>> class Cfg (object):
...   KEY_VALUES = (
...     ('f', 1), ('s', 2), ('t', 3)
...   )
...   def __init__ (self):
...     for k, v in Cfg.KEY_VALUES:
...       setattr (self, f'{k}_', v)
... 
>>> for k, v in Cfg.KEY_VALUES:
...   setattr (Cfg, k, property (lambda self: getattr (self, f'{k}_')))
... 
>>> Cfg.f
<property object at 0x7f46aa69d278>
>>> Cfg ().f
3
>>> Cfg ().f_
1
>>> Cfg.s
<property object at 0x7f46aa69d368>
>>> Cfg ().s
3
>>> Cfg ().s_
2
>>> Cfg.t
<property object at 0x7f46aa69d408>
>>> Cfg ().t
3
>>> Cfg ().t_
3
```

Why I'm getting always "last" value if I'm accessing different properties
Could you please explain what I'm doing wrong? And is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: I don't know why you think a list of pairs *and* a loop is an improvement over a list of assignments.

Comment: Why are you not using a dict?

Comment: The problem is that you aren't creating a different getter for each property. `k` inside the lambda expression is just a name, and looked up when the getter is *used*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't defining a closure over the current value of `k` when you define the properties. Every property has the exact same getter, a function that looks up the value of a variable named `k` when it gets called.

You would need something like the following, which makes the getter a closure over the argument of a function that gets called when the property is defined,

```
class Cfg (object):
  KEY_VALUES = (
    ('f', 1), ('s', 2), ('t', 3)
  )
  def __init__ (self):
    for k, v in Cfg.KEY_VALUES:
      setattr (Cfg, k, property (lambda x: 
                                  (lambda self: getattr (self, f'{x}_'))(k)))
```

which is just awful. Honestly, I would stick with

```
class Cfg:
    f = property(lambda self: 1)
    s = property(lambda self: 2)
    t = property(lambda self: 3)
```

It's perfectly straightforward, and the DRY principle doesn't require you to wring every last drop of redundancy from your code. If you really want to further abstract the idea of a read-only property, you could write

```
def constantproperty(x):
    return property(lambda self: x)

class Cfg:
    f = constantproperty(1)
    s = constantproperty(2)
    t = constantproperty(3)
```

Regarding your original concern, if you have a long list of key/value pairs, then your object should probably store a single list or dict in the first place, rather than a bunch of indepenedent attributes. (Or your class needs to be broken down into smaller classes, but that's beyond the scope of this question.)

```
class Cfg:
    def __init__(self):
        self.kv = {'f': 1, 's': 2, 't': 3}
```

Comment: Thank you @chepner . I guess I do not understand clearly "closure" and this "not understanding" caused this question and unfortunately still is not quite clear...
About having this dynamic properties creation - just imagine you have 40 possible key/value pairs (and this is my real use case) and, obviously, from maintenance point of view, dynamic creation would be a winner even with (according to you :) ) with that "awful" solution ...

Comment: A good text editor makes the creation of the individual properties trivial. You're going to have a long list of key/value pairs in one form or another; why add to the cognitive load of the reader by making them read a loop?

Comment: Actually I agree about that solution  - it is "awful" since it requres existence of Cfg's instance (self in lambda). I think there is other solution that inspired by yours. It is using some "helper":
`
class Helper (object):
    def __init__ (self, v):
        self.v = f'{v}_'
    def __call__ (self, the_instance):
        return getattr (the_instance, self.v)
# global loop
for k, v in Cfg.KEY_VALUES:
    setattr (Cfg, k, property (lambda self: Helper (k)))
`
At least above works for me.
Thanks again
Sorry, don't know how here to show "as code"

Comment: Well, @chepner, It is kind of philosophical question.... Most of the time it would be me who have deal with this code. So first, I guess, I should worry about myself. Plus again, add/delete/edit any key/value pair would be in one place only, which will significantly benefit maintenance efforts...